# I keep to the path my master has bestowed

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry

> My prefix should come before an action
>   For without, it is likely to fail
>   My infix is part of a path 
>   On which you may ride or sail
>
> My suffix is an interconnection 
>   That links many a node 
>   I keep to the humble path 
>   That my master has bestowed

Who am I?

Comment: For those who are unfamiliar, this is a Riley riddle

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you are a

> **planet**

My prefix should come before an action
For without, it is likely to fail

> **plan**et

My infix is part of a path
On which you may ride or sail

> p**lane**t

My suffix is an interconnection
That links many a node

> pla**net**

I keep to the humble path
That my master has bestowed

> The Sun keeps the planet on its orbit.